# Python (2.x) - Remove character from key in list of dicts

Tags: python

I have trouble recursively removing unwanted characters from keys of python dict with list of dicts inside it. I am trying to remove "#" and "@" signs from all the **keys** in the dataset by using a recursive solution that doesn't require me to hardcode all fields in the code.

```
{
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "some name",
    "contact_info": {
        "phone": { "@suppress": "false", "#number": "123456789" }
    },
    "categories": {
        "category ": [
            { "@primary ": "true", "@parentid ": "1234", "@nameid ": "5678", "@name ": "Category name 1" }, 
            { "@primary ": "false", "@parentid ": "5678", "@nameid ": "2532", "@name ": "Category name 2" } 
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I used so far that can deal with the dicts, but I am having problems dealing with list of dicts (item: category).

```
import json

def remove_chars(obj):
        for key in obj.keys():
                if isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                        obj[key] = remove_chars(obj[key])
                new_key = key.replace("@","").replace("#","")
                if new_key != key:
                        obj[new_key] = obj[key]
                        del obj[key]
        return obj

a = json.loads('{ "id": "123456", "name": "some name", "contact_info": { "phone": { "@suppress": "false", "#number": "123456789" } }, "categories": { "category ": [ { "@primary ": "true", "@parentid ": "1234", "@nameid ": "5678", "@name ": "Category name 1" },  { "@primary ": "false", "@parentid ": "5678", "@nameid ": "2532", "@name ": "Category name 2" }  ] } }')

print a
print remove_chars(a)
```

Here are the respective outputs:
The first one is okay as it removes the @ and # signs from the first dict. But the ones under the list are not handled correctly.

```
{u'contact_info': {u'phone': {u'@suppress': u'false', u'#number': u'123456789'}}, u'id': u'123456', u'categories': {u'category ': [{u'@parentid ': u'1234', u'@name ': u'Category name 1', u'@nameid ': u'5678', u'@primary ': u'true'}, {u'@parentid ': u'5678', u'@name ': u'Category name 2', u'@nameid ': u'2532', u'@primary ': u'false'}]}, u'name': u'some name'}

{u'contact_info': {u'phone': {u'suppress': u'false', u'number': u'123456789'}}, u'id': u'123456', u'categories': {u'category ': [{u'@parentid ': u'1234', u'@name ': u'Category name 1', u'@nameid ': u'5678', u'@primary ': u'true'}, {u'@parentid ': u'5678', u'@name ': u'Category name 2', u'@nameid ': u'2532', u'@primary ': u'false'}]}, u'name': u'some name'}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you are seeking debugging help, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You show me your solution I'll show you mine.

Comment: Plz share codez.... thx

Comment: Added the code and outputs so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the changes to happen in-place, this is the straightforward way. It just brute-force walks through the data structure, making pretty rigid assumptions about what it contains:

```
>>> def replace_keys(data, replacer):
...     if isinstance(data, dict):
...         return {replacer(k): replace_keys(v, replacer) for k, v in data.items()}
...     elif isinstance(data, list):
...         return [replace_keys(val, replacer) for val in data]
...     else:
...         return data
...
>>> def replacer(s):
...    return s.translate({35: '', 64: ''})
...
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{'categories': {'category ': [{'@name ': 'Category name 1',
                               '@nameid ': '5678',
                               '@parentid ': '1234',
                               '@primary ': 'true'},
                              {'@name ': 'Category name 2',
                               '@nameid ': '2532',
                               '@parentid ': '5678',
                               '@primary ': 'false'}]},
 'contact_info': {'phone': {'#number': '123456789', '@suppress': 'false'}},
 'id': '123456',
 'name': 'some name'}
>>> pprint(replace_keys(data, replacer))
{'categories': {'category ': [{'name ': 'Category name 1',
                               'nameid ': '5678',
                               'parentid ': '1234',
                               'primary ': 'true'},
                              {'name ': 'Category name 2',
                               'nameid ': '2532',
                               'parentid ': '5678',
                               'primary ': 'false'}]},
 'contact_info': {'phone': {'number': '123456789', 'suppress': 'false'}},
 'id': '123456',
 'name': 'some name'}
```

Again, this creates a copy of your original data-structure, which isn't mutated. Doing this in-place will be significantly more annoying.

The above assumes your keys are always strings. Also, this function is potentially lossy, which is inherent to your operation. If two distinct keys somehow map to the same new key, only one is kept due to the nature of dictionaries.

Comment: I am having trouble with the translate function under 2.7.5. I keep getting a TypeError. `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Trying `return s.replace(None, '@#')` doesn't work either.

Comment: @PrashantChaudhary Then you can simply use `return s.replace('#', '').replace('@','')`. Note, `replacer` can be whatever you want that takes a string and returns a replacement.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga ... that solution works. While it seems costly to keep creating a copy for each processed record, it works for me because I am processing 5k record in one go and the system can handle it.

Comment: @PrashantChaudhary as long as memory isn't a concern, this is likely *faster* than modifying in place, due to all the complications it introduces (having to delete keys, which you shouldn't do while iterating over the dictionary)